# high chart total data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I try to populate chart when user click on button .. and chart is display like this

[image]

now the problem i want total i.e. as in image in red circle i write TOTAL : `3 .. 3 is beacuse 2 for MV and 1 for DSB so total is 3` 
I try this

this is the code which i try

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var strArray = "[['sfdsdfLi', 9],['Kiwsdfi', 3],['Mixesdfd nuts', 1],['Oranges', 6],['Grapes (bunch)', 1]]";
    $(function () {
        $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
            var obj = {};
            obj.ID = Id;
            GetData(obj);
            return false;
        });
    });
function GetData(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result !== null && result.length == 0) {
                $("#cont").hide();
                return;
            }
            strArray = result.d;
            var myarray = eval(strArray);
            $("#cont").show();
            $('#cont').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    borderColor: 'Grey',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Data1'
                },

            position: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    x: 10,
                    y: -10
              },
            subtitle: {
                text: '3D Chart'
            },


            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    innerSize: 100,
                    depth: 45,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',

                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Delivered amount',
                    data: myarray
                }]
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    });
        }
  </script>
```

now how i get total  ? any solutions

Comment: Your series should have total parameter, you can use chart.renderer.text to render new text with total value in your chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/f7m3byj6/